# Routing url with several params

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to build a REST API with ASP mvc and i'm having some trouble with the routing.

I would like to match the following urls in a nice and convenient way:

```
https://foo.com/collections/
https://foo.com/collections.json/
https://foo.com/collections.xml/

https://foo.com/collections/collectionID/
https://foo.com/collections/collectionID.json/
https://foo.com/collections/collectionID.xml/
```

And in future more items on the same pattern:

```
https://foo.com/persons/
https://foo.com/persons.json/
https://foo.com/persons.xml/

https://foo.com/persons/personID/
https://foo.com/persons/personID.json/
https://foo.com/persons/personID.xml/
```

My best attempt so far is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RESTCollections",
    url: "{controller}s/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Collection", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RESTCollections",
    url: "{controller}s/{format}/",
    defaults: new { controller="Collection", action="Index", format = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { format = "json|xml|html" }
);
```

It manages to match:

```
https://foo.com/collections/
https://foo.com/collections/json
```

But I'm stuck there trying to replace the "/" between the controller and format gives 404. Simply removing the "/" also gives 404.

Comment: for using period in mvc urls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273987/asp-net-mvc-url-route-supporting-dot

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: How to Route Search Term with . (Period) at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332757/asp-net-mvc-how-to-route-search-term-with-period-at-the-end)

Comment: Are you using Web Api?
If so, you can route your methods like this:
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/persons/]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll() { ... }
  
  [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/persons.json/]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllJson() { ... }

[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/persons.xml/]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllXml() { ... }

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you could try

```
 `context.MapRoute(
    "Api_default",
    "{controller}/{action}.{format}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", format = UrlParameter.Optional });`
```

As stated here [stackoverflow.com/.../customizing-asp-net-mvc-routing-to-service-json-xml-style-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210200/customizing-asp-net-mvc-routing-to-service-json-xml-style-urls)

On the other hand I don't see why you would like to state which format you want to accept to be sent to your API.

You could use the `[FromBody] string content` which deserialises the sent value to the method.

Or you could define the type of the parameter with the Route attribute

```
[Route("Post/{collection:string}")
public void Post(string collection)
```

Where string is a predefined constraint, you can create your own custom constraints.

Comment: I just want the .json declaration as an overrride of the normal accept-header content negotiation.

Comment: I think my main problem is that ISS is not built to handle dots in urls, it is possible but seems to require an unsafe setting.